# PG_FETCH_ARRAY() doesn't return any data

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the following problem with `pg_fetch_array()`, this is the code:

```
// Controllo utente
$u= "SELECT FROM utente WHERE idutente = '$username' and password= '$password'"; 
$result = pg_query($db,$u) or die(pg_last_error()); 
    
//Controllo query
if (!$result) {echo "problemi con la query"." ".$u;}
    
$tuplaUtente = pg_fetch_array($result);
    
// Numero di tuple
if ($tuplaUtente === false) {echo "error fetch";}
else {
    echo $tuplaUtente['idutente'];
    echo "else";
}
    
pg_close();
```

This code shows only "else", despite using PgAdmin the "$u" query returns the correctly result.

In fact, if I type in the last else:

```
else {                                            
    var_dump($tuplaUtente);
    echo $u;
    echo "else";
}
```

It shows `array(0) { } SELECT FROM utente WHERE idutente = 'usr' and password= 'pwd'else`.

Comment: You're checking `$tuplaUtente === false` - that's checking to see if `$tuplaUtente` is a boolean false, which your var_dump shows it is not - you're getting an empty array, not a false. I suspect your query is finding no valid results, as opposed to failing.

Comment: Try `echo pg_num_rows($result)` to verify that there were records returned.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the else in this mode: 
                                              {   
                                                  echo "else"." with number ".pg_num_rows($result)." ".$tuplautente['idutente'];
                                                  
                                                  }
It return: "else with number 1".

Comment: You should have a column list after your `SELECT`, like `SELECT idutente FROM` or `SELECT * FROM`.  Although I would have assumed your code would have failed at the `pg_query` step as it is now...

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Additionally, you really shouldn't be using the Postgres driver directly. At the **absolute least** use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT FROM utente WHERE idutente = '$username' and password= '$password'
```

does not return any column, as @Jerrad commented.

This used to be invalid SQL before PostgreSQL 9.4, but is allowed since then, see the [Release Notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4.html):

> E.7.3.3. Queries
>
> [...]
>
> Allow SELECT to have an empty target list (Tom Lane)

This lack of any output column is why the array returned by `pg_fetch_array` is empty: the result itself has one row but zero column.

It's obviously a mistake in the query: given the rest of the code, it should have at least the `idutente` column just after the SELECT.